# Getting error NDSolve:ndnum when solving a nonlinear coupled differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I have to solve a set of coupled equations for the jump phenomenon in rotor imbalance case. Where I have to plot Vs vs steady state y'[t]

```
c=5
k2 = 10
e = 0.005
I1 = 0.001
k1 = 40000
M = 1
m = 0.03
mum = 0.08
Rm = 2
Vs = 17
eqn =
{x''[t] ==
(-c*(I1 + e^2*m) x'[t] - k1*(I1 + e^2*m) x[t] - k2*(I1 + e^2*m) + 
m^2*e^2*sin[y[t]]*cos[y[t]]*x'[t] + m*e*(I1 + e^2*m)*cos[y[t]] +
(mum/Rm)*m*e*sin[y[t]]*(Vs - mum*y'[t]))/((M + m)*(I1 + e^2*m) - 
m^2*e^2*((sin[y[t]])^2)),
y''[t] ==
(-c*e*m*sin[y[t]]*x'[t] - k1*e*m*sin[y[t]]*x[t] - 
k2*e*m*sin[y[t]]*(x[t])^3 + (M + m)*e*cos[y[t]]*m*x'[t] + 
m^2*e^2*sin[y[t]]*cos[y[t]]*
y'[t]^2 + ((M + m)*mum/Rm)*(Vs - mum*y'[t]))/((M + m)*(I1 + 
e^2*m) - m^2*e^2*((sin[y[t]])^2)), x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0, 
y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[eqn, {x, y}, {t, 0, 200}]
```

Ends up with the error

> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0

Any help would be appreciated. Also sorry for the formatting I have a class in 10 minutes and will format it better when I get back.

Comment: `sin[]` should be `Sin[]` and the same for `Cos[]`

Comment: What you mean you want to plot `Vs` vs ....? You already assigned value for `Vs=17`.

Comment: @MapleSE-Area51Proposal it was just a testcase to check if the code was right

Comment: What you mean by state state here?

Comment: After correcting the `sin` mistake mentioned by @maple you need `MaxSteps->Infinity` then everything is OK.

Comment: @MapleSE-Area51Proposal y' is the angular velocity,I need the angular velocity after transient part dies down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0

This error massage can be addressed by using the correct syntax for `Sin` and `Cos`. But you will still get the following warning,

> NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 10000 steps reached at the point t ==
>   11.041244410956859`.

As suggested in the comment by @xzczd, use `MaxSteps -> Infinity` inside `NDSolve`.

To keep a parameter unassigned, one way is to use `ParametricNDSolve`.

```
Clear[c, k2, e, I1, k1, M, m, mum, Rm, Vs]

c = 5; k2 = 10; e = 0.005; I1 = 0.001; k1 = 40000; M = 1; m = 0.03; mum = 0.08; Rm = 2;

eqn = {x''[t] == (-c*(I1 + e^2*m) x'[t] - k1*(I1 + e^2*m) x[t] - 
       k2*(I1 + e^2*m) + m^2*e^2*Sin[y[t]]*Cos[y[t]]*x'[t] + 
       m*e*(I1 + e^2*m)*Cos[y[t]] + (mum/Rm)*m*e*
        Sin[y[t]]*(Vs - mum*y'[t]))/((M + m)*(I1 + e^2*m) - m^2*e^2*((Sin[y[t]])^2)), 
      y''[t] == (-c*e*m*Sin[y[t]]*x'[t] - k1*e*m*Sin[y[t]]*x[t] - 
       k2*e*m*Sin[y[t]]*(x[t])^3 + (M + m)*e*Cos[y[t]]*m*x'[t] + 
       m^2*e^2*Sin[y[t]]*Cos[y[t]]*
       y'[t]^2 + ((M + m)*mum/Rm)*(Vs - mum*y'[t]))/((M + m)*(I1 + 
       e^2*m) - m^2*e^2*((Sin[y[t]])^2)), x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0, 
     y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0};

sol = ParametricNDSolve[eqn, {x, y}, {t, 0, 200}, {Vs}, MaxSteps -> Infinity];

ysol[Vs_] = y[Vs][t] /. sol;

Table[NIntegrate[D[ysol[Vs], t], {t, 5, 20}]/15, {Vs, 0.0, 1, 0.1}];

ListLinePlot[%, DataRange -> {0.0, 1}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**Edit**

In response to OP's comment.

If you use `Method -> "LocalAdaptive"` and `PrecisionGoal -> 11` inside `NIntegrate`, you will get an output without any warning but it is time consuming.

```
Table[NIntegrate[D[ysol[Vs], t], {t, 5, 20}, PrecisionGoal -> 11, 
                 Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]/15, {Vs, 10.0, 30, 1}];
ListLinePlot[%, DataRange -> {10.0, 30}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: This is exacty what I want but for voltages ranging from 10 to 20 the numerical integration give an error doesnt converge or singular.

Comment: No, The result holds good. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to plot angular velocity Y'[t]:
Based on your question, you may try like this:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
c = 5;
k2 = 10;
e = 0.005;
I1 = 0.001; 
k1 = 40000;
M = 1;
m = 0.03;
mum = 0.08;
Rm = 2;
Vs = 17;
```

your equation:

```
eqn = {x''[t] == (-c*(I1 + e^2*m) x'[t] - k1*(I1 + e^2*m) x[t] - 
   k2*(I1 + e^2*m) + m^2*e^2*Sin[y[t]]*Cos[y[t]]*x'[t] + 
   m*e*(I1 + e^2*m)*Cos[y[t]] + (mum/Rm)*m*e*
    Sin[y[t]]*(Vs - mum*y'[t]))/((M + m)*(I1 + e^2*m) - 
   m^2*e^2*((Sin[y[t]])^2)),

y''[t] == (-c*e*m*Sin[y[t]]*x'[t] - k1*e*m*Sin[y[t]]*x[t] - 
   k2*e*m*Sin[y[t]]*(x[t])^3 + (M + m)*e*Cos[y[t]]*m*x'[t] + 
   m^2*e^2*Sin[y[t]]*Cos[y[t]]*
    y'[t]^2 + ((M + m)*mum/Rm)*(Vs - mum*y'[t]))/((M + m)*(I1 + 
      e^2*m) - m^2*e^2*((Sin[y[t]])^2)), x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0,

y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0};
```

Solution

```
sol = NDSolve[eqn, {x, y}, {t, 0, 200}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]

out:{{x -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 200.}}, <>], 
 y -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 200.}}, <>]}}
```

Plot variables:

```
   X = First[x /. sol];
   Y = Last[y /. sol];

   Plot[X[t], {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

```
   Plot[Y[t], {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

Plot angular velocity:

```
   Plot[Y'[t], {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there an quicker way to plot Vs vs steady state y'[t] other than writing a loop? Where the steady state value of y'[t] would be NIntegrate[y'[t], {t, 5, 20}]/15 since it oscillates over an approximate range of 0.013rad/sec . for voltages ranging from 10 to 30.

Comment: what is the range of Vs or data for Vs?

Comment: Voltage ranges from 10-25